# How to set up Cloudfront with EC2 website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to AWS and hoping someone can answer my question here. I've created a web server on an EC2 instance and installed Craft CMS on it. I've requested a public certificate from Certificate Manager, and put the CNAME in the route53 hosted zone for the domain name. The certificate is attached to the Load balancer I attached to my EC2 instance. If I set up cloudfront with all this my website is still showing up as insecure (meaning I'm not doing something right). How should I go about connecting cloudfront to my EC2 instance? With or without the load balancer. I only have one instance running so I don't really need the load balancer either. Thanks!

Comment: Does your CloudFront Distribution use your EC2-based web server as its origin?  And does your Route53 CNAME entry point to the cloudfront hostname?

Comment: CloudFront only lets me select from S3 buckets or ELB (which is why I made the ELB in the first place). So I attached it to ELB which is attached to the EC2 instance. The CNAME was pointing to the ELB as well.

Comment: The CNAME is from AWS Certificate Manager which also shows that the ELB is attached to it as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify what you are trying to accomplish: 1) You have one or more EC2 instances, presumably in an auto-scaling group; 2) Those EC2 instances are set as targets for your ELB; 3) You have a certificate that is valid for your ELB hostname, let's call it elb.mydomain.com.

And now you are trying to setup CloudFront with the ELB as the origin?

Starting with the CloudFront certificate: Is the certificate also valid for your CloudFront hostname (let's call it [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com))?  If not, you will need to create and validate another cert for [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com).

Second, the CloudFront distribution must be configured to use a certificate that is valid for the hostname you want to use.  You must also include the hostname as an alternate domain name in the CloudFront distribution.  Then make sure your route53 CNAME entry points from your desired hostname to the CloudFront distribution, which will be something like d18sdfijsilj.cloudfront.net.

Comment: I just deleted the ELB, Target Group, CloudFront distribution, and the certificate from Certificate Manager. I'll follow these steps now based on my understanding of your answer (and thank you for helping out here!). Right now I've created an elastic IP and attached that to my EC2 instance and routing that to my domain name from Route53

1) Create a certificate from AWS Certificate Manager for the domain name mydomain.net

2) Enter a CNAME record for the certificate to prove DNS ownership

Comment: 3) Create an ELB (CloudFront only lets me select from S3 or ELB and not EC2 otherwise I'd skip this) and associate it with my EC2 instance


4) Create a CloudFront distribution using the ELB as the source, and add mydomain.net in the alternate domain name section (Sometimes it doesn't allow for that to be entered for some reason)

5) Delete the record in route53 routing to the EC2 instance via elastic IP and create a CNAME to do so toward the cloudfront distribution

Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right, however, if you are only using ELB because you can only connect CloudFront to S3 or ELB, I think that is not correct.  Normally I set things up with CloudFormation rather than the web console, but the CloudFormation documentation here says that you can use the CustomOriginConfig to set "Any other HTTP server, running on an Amazon EC2 instance or any other kind of host".  Sometimes things are hard to find in the web console, but this may simplify things.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html